# Do players like holiday events?

Tags: game-design, user-experience

I remember back when I played runescape, they always had these really interactive holiday events. And players would be squirming all around trying to find where it was. After you would complete it (it was like a mini-quest), you would be rewarded with some kind of item. I thought it was really cool, but if you missed the event you'd be pooped out. And now days, I play simpler games, such as [parallel kingdom](http://www.parallelkingdom.com/), and they just have boring items that you can buy for holidays.

Is it worth making holiday events, or could you get by without them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holiday events can be made as an incentive to get "fun" stuff, but as mentioned don't make them game-breaking qualities. Then players can get bragging rights over others who missed out on the promotion. It also lets people know that the creators are still putting in their effort to keep supporting the game.

Also, Animal Crossing is a good offline example. It uses the Gamecube's system clock to keep the town in time each year, so you can see a Christmas celerbration or New Years countdown. And I believe that in some mornings, some of the townsfolk even go out for a morning jog!

Answer (score 5):

Looking at Team Fortress 2, yes, players do. Holiday events are good, they bring old and new players to your game. But make them really funny - not just a little item set or a 10% deal. And if you add holiday items, don't make them overpowered and game-obstructing. It's your choice make holiday events or not, but I recommend you to make them to increase lifetime and popularity of your game.